# Multiple Check boxes in cake php

Tags: function, cakephp, checkbox

I have a list of bookings and I want to delete them using multiple checkboxes. Here is my code:

```
foreach ($bookings as $booking): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo h($booking['Booking']['first_name']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($booking['Booking']['surname']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($booking['Booking']['created']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form-> checkbox('Bookings.ID.['.$booking['Booking']['ID'].']', 
        array('value' => $booking['Booking']['ID']));?></td>    
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and in my controller I use this function to delete the selected bookings:

```
public function deletebooking(){

    $bookings = $this->Booking->find('all');
    $this->set('bookings',$bookings);
    if(!empty($this->data)){
        foreach($this->data[Bookings] as $key => $value){

            if($value != 0){
                $this->Booking->delete($value);
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me why it is not working?

Comment: Please provide more information.  Is there an error?  How far is it getting into your code?  Is it getting to your function at all?  Is it doing the foreach()?  If so, what are the value(s)? ...etc etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Change your input field to the following:
foreach ($bookings as $booking): ?>

```
<td>
   <?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('bookingids', 
                                      array(
                                        'value' => $booking['Booking']['ID'],
                                        'name' => 'data[Booking][bookingids][]',
                                       ));?>
</td>
```

Notice the empty `[]` in the name value. This will create a new index of that array. In your controller you would access it like this:

```
   if(!empty($this->data)) :
        foreach($this->data['Bookings']['bookingids'] as $key => $value):
                $data = array();
                $data['Booking']['id'] = $value;
                $this->Booking->delete($data);
        endforeach;
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    endif;
```